# Sql query with joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables, book and temp_table.
There are 2 columns in book : `book_id and tag_id`, and only 1 column in temp_table (`tag_id`).

I need do selection used following rule:

- If book has ALL the tags from temp_table, it will be in result.

For example, there are 3 books.

```
   First one has tag_id: 1,2,3,4.
   Second - 1,3,4
   Third - 1,2,3,5
```

And temp_table contains tag_id:`1,3,4`.

Needed selection has to contains 1st and 2nd books. 3d book must not be in result set because it has tag_id = 5, which there isnt in temp_table.

Comment: If 3rd book can't be in the result because it has tag_id=5, why does the 1st book should come up in the results if it has tag_id=2, since temp_table doesn't have tag_id=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select book_id
from book b
inner join temp_table t on t.tag_id = tag_id
group by book_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = (select count(distinct tag_id) from temp_table)
```